# Redirected View not displaying "active" attribute in MVC application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a new MVC 4 application that I am playing with.  Basically, a few menu items across the top, with the currently active page being highlighted with the follow JavaScript in my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#top-navbar .nav a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

That works great when navigating via the menu across the top.  However, I am adding a "login" ability, and if the user tries to go back to the login page after they are already logged in, it will simply send them the `Index` view instead of the `Login` view.  The problem is, the CSS is still highlighting the `Login` button in the menu, rather than the `Home` button.

I am persisting the user's login information via the `Session` state.  Here is the `Login()` `ActionResult`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    if (Session["ContactName"] != null)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

As you can see, if the `ContactName` is not `null` then they are already logged in, so it sends them the `Home` view.  Should I instead `Redirect()` to the main page?

Also, here is the menu `navbar` if needed:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Customer Login", "Login", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should return a `RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")`. What you have is simply using the Index view but the url will still reflect the Login state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your client side still sees the URL as `/Login` rather than the index so you are better off redirecting the user. You can do this using the [`RedirectToAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470594%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) controller method and giving it the controller and action name that returns your index view:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    if (Session["ContactName"] != null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, `RedirectToAction()` was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can remove your JQuery for setting the active menu and use this in your navbar tag:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Index" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "About" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Contact" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

Or you could implement some HtmlHelper to do the same thing like how it is shown in this post:
http://chrisondotnet.com/2012/08/setting-active-link-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: This works great.  I was trying to find a nice solution, and the JQuery one was previously the simplest I was able to come up with.  This one is nice and doesn't require any scripting!